# Python - TypeError: string indices must be integers when handling Bing JSON data

Tags: python, json, typeerror, bing

I know this question has been asked many times, but I've tried everything and don't know where I'm going wrong.

I'm trying to use Bing's Geolocator API to get the coordinates of a certain city I input it. Here's my code:

```
# Prepare our URL with making our arguments usable
city = sys.argv[1]
city = city.replace(" ", "\%20")
state = sys.argv[2]
           
# Now let's create the Bing API URL
bingURL = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" + city + "\%20\%2C" + state + "&key=" + key
            
# Now to get our geolocation data
with urllib.request.urlopen(bingURL) as url:
    bingData = json.dumps(url.read().decode())
useData = json.loads(bingData)

print(useData)         

lat = useData["resourceSets"]["0"]["resources"]["0"]["geocodePoints"]["0"]["coordinates"]["0"]
print(lat)
```

That was just a snippet of the problematic code, it's being used in a decently sized script. Anyway, here's the output:

```
$ ./getter.py New\ York NY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./getter.py", line 49, in <module>
    lat = useData["resourceSets"]["0"]["resources"]["0"]["geocodePoints"]["0"]["coordinates"]["0"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

(I've hidden the JSON output because of Microsoft's copyright string at the the top, but the JSON data did show up for me.)

I do not understand why this doesn't work. I am new to working with JSON, but I think I'm doing everything right. I'm reading from a string of JSON data, I'm using json.loads, and I'm fairly certain my path is correct. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If you can't share the JSON data, it would be pretty hard for us to figure out the issue. One thing you can do is to just iteratively remove the indexes from your big `useData[...]` line until you find the problematic index. Then, print the type of the data at that point to help debug what's wrong. One thing that looks suspicious to me is that you're using index `"0"` as a string instead of an int, but I can't say for sure without seeing the JSON data.

Comment: @rchome Ok, well would it be okay to share my JSON data? It says in the copyright string "This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.", which makes me think I can't share the data. I agree with you that it would be easier if I could show it, so if I can, I will. I also did try to use 0 as an int, and it didn't work either, so I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: Maybe you can at least replace the data within the JSON with fake data so the structure of the JSON is the same without revealing the actual values. I am not a lawyer though, so it's up to you. Also, it would probably help if you stripped out any of the irrelevant fields in your JSON data so we can quickly identify the issue.